# Pass an array item to a function in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I've already read many articles about PowerShell functions and passing parameters to them but I haven't found a solution on how to pass a specific array item to a function and not the full array.
This is how my code looks:

```
$log = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
$test = "asdf"
$arrtest = @("one", "two", "three")

Function Write-Log($message)
{
    Write-Host $message
    $message | Out-File $log -Append
}
```

Now I want to pass single items of the array to the Write-Log function like this:

```
Write-Log "first arr item: $arrtest[0]"
Write-Log "second arr item: $arrtest[1]"
Write-Log "third arr item: $arrtest[2]"
```

But in the commandline I'll always get the full array plus [number] as a string:

```
first arr item: one two three[0]
second arr item: one two three[1]
third arr item: one two three[2]
```

I think the problem is my syntax, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

`Write-Log "first arr item: $($arrtest[0])"`

In your attempt, your passing entire array, because PowerShell interprets `$arrtest` as variable, and `[0]` as string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast solution!